# Variable not declared in scope and a defined function cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++

This is how the code currently looks like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int cos(angle)
{
    float rad = angle;
    float radPh = 1;
    float facto = 1;
    float tOld = 1;
    float tNew = 0;
    float tPh = 1;
    float tDiff = 1;
    float cosAns;

    precision = precision + 1;
    float x = 10;
    float finalPr = 1;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < precision; ++counter)
    {
        finalPr /= x;
    }

    finalPr = 0.5 * finalPr;

    while (tDiff > finalPr)
        {
            tOld = tPh;
            tNew = ((-1)*tOld*rad*rad)/((facto+1)*(facto+2));
            tPh = tNew;
            radPh = tNew;
            facto = facto + 2;
            tDiff = tOld - tNew;
            cosAns = radPh;
        }

    return cosAns;
}

int main()
{
    int precision = 10;
    int choice;

    //Title and Menu
    cout << endl << "==============" << endl << " TRIGONOMETRY " << endl << "==============";
    cout << endl << endl << "Current Precision: " << precision;
    cout << endl << "Select:";
    cout << endl << "1. Change Decimal Precision";
    cout << endl << "2. Calculate Cos and Sin";
    cout << endl << "9. Exit";

    while (true)
    {
        //User Prompt
        cout << endl << endl << "Please enter your choice. => ";
        cin >> choice;
        
        if (choice == 1)
            {
                cout << endl << "Please enter a value between 2 and 10. => ";
                cin >> precision;
                cout << "Current precision is " << precision;
            }

        if (choice == 2)
            {
                float angle, anglePh;
                float pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716;
                char angleType;

                cout << endl << "Please enter an angle. => ";
                cin >> angle;
                cout << endl << "Is the angle in degrees or in radian?";
                cout << endl << "Input D if it's in degrees,";
                cout << endl << "Input R if it's in radian. => ";
                cin >> angleType;
                    if (angleType == 'D')
                    {
                        anglePh = angle;
                        angle = angle*pi/180;
                        cout << anglePh << " degrees = " << angle << " radian";
                    }
                
                cout << endl << "Calculating Cos...";
                cos(angle);
                cout << endl << "Calculating Sin...";
            }
        
        if (choice == 9)
            {
                break;
            }
    }
    
}
```

I am building a program that gets the angle from the user and then convert it into radian before calculating its Sine and Cosine values. When I run this code it tells me that the angle from "int cos(angle)" was not defined, so I tried moving it into the if loop for choice 2, but it didn't solve the issue. It also says that cos(angle) cannot be used as a function when I tried to trigger it from the if loop for choice 2. Any ideas on this?

I actually made a similar program using Python back then, and this method that I used to write the program worked. I know there are some differences between Python and C++, but I thought the general idea would still apply.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: `int cos(angle) {` is a bad function declaration. You probably meant `int cos(float angle) {`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @scohe001 `float cos(float angle)` looks better at first grance, but it won't make much difference because the returned value is not used anyway. More important thing is that the name `cos` is used in the standard library and is confusing.

Comment: Ahh you're right @Mike. I guess this should be a dupe of "why shouldn't we `using namespace std;`?" then.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I'll correct it accordingly. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function definition/declaration you must mention the argument data type.

> int cos(float angle, int precision)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int cos(float angle, int precision)
{
    float rad = angle;
    float radPh = 1;
    float facto = 1;
    float tOld = 1;
    float tNew = 0;
    float tPh = 1;
    float tDiff = 1;
    float cosAns;


    precision = precision + 1;
    float x = 10;
    float finalPr = 1;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < precision; ++counter)
    {
        finalPr /= x;
    }

    finalPr = 0.5 * finalPr;

    while (tDiff > finalPr)
        {
            tOld = tPh;
            tNew = ((-1)*tOld*rad*rad)/((facto+1)*(facto+2));
            tPh = tNew;
            radPh = tNew;
            facto = facto + 2;
            tDiff = tOld - tNew;
            cosAns = radPh;
        }

    return cosAns;
}

int main()
{
    int precision = 10;
    int choice;

    //Title and Menu
    cout << endl << "==============" << endl << " TRIGONOMETRY " << endl << "==============";
    cout << endl << endl << "Current Precision: " << precision;
    cout << endl << "Select:";
    cout << endl << "1. Change Decimal Precision";
    cout << endl << "2. Calculate Cos and Sin";
    cout << endl << "9. Exit";

    while (true)
    {
        //User Prompt
        cout << endl << endl << "Please enter your choice. => ";
        cin >> choice;
        
        if (choice == 1)
            {
                cout << endl << "Please enter a value between 2 and 10. => ";
                cin >> precision;
                cout << "Current precision is " << precision;
            }

        if (choice == 2)
            {
                float angle, anglePh;
                float pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716;
                char angleType;

                cout << endl << "Please enter an angle. => ";
                cin >> angle;
                cout << endl << "Is the angle in degrees or in radian?";
                cout << endl << "Input D if it's in degrees,";
                cout << endl << "Input R if it's in radian. => ";
                cin >> angleType;
                    if (angleType == 'D')
                    {
                        anglePh = angle;
                        angle = angle*pi/180;
                        cout << anglePh << " degrees = " << angle << " radian";
                    }
                
                cout << endl << "Calculating Cos...";
                cout <<cos(angle, precision);
                cout << endl << "Calculating Sin...";
            }
        
        if (choice == 9)
            {
                break;
            }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Note: The OP's code doesn't accept `precision` as an argument. Though the OP's code doesn't declare `precision` in `cos()`, so that would be another problem if you didn't accept it as an argument. I suppose it's not a big deal, but I thought I'd mention it anyway.